# Can't locate API module structure `mod_wsgi'

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-wsgi, trac

I'm working on setting up `Trac` to use `wsgi`, and am running into trouble getting mod_wsgi working.  I downloaded and installed mod_sgi.

[box]# **apachectl configtest**

httpd: Syntax error on line 214 of /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf: Can't locate API module structure `mod_wsgi' in file /etc/httpd/modules/mod_wsgi.so: /etc/httpd/modules/mod_wsgi.so: undefined symbol: mod_wsgi

Line 214 of httpd.conf:

```
LoadModule mod_wsgi modules/mod_wsgi.so
```

Here is mod_wsgi.so as found on the filesystem:

```
[box]# locate mod_wsgi.so
/usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_wsgi.so
```

What might I be overlooking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This particular problem was solved by installing `python26-mod_wsgi.so`.

Answer (score 12):

The line:

```
LoadModule mod_wsgi modules/mod_wsgi.so
```

is wrong. It should have been:

```
LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so
```

Upgrading itself should not have made any difference.

Comment: My problem was not exactly this but was with mod_jk.so; it helped me figure out. Thanks @Graham