# Cannot run mod_wsgi on Apache 2.4 x64 Windows

Tags: apache-2.4, mod-wsgi

I have a Apache 2.2 installation with a site on Django. I load mod_wsgi.so module in my Apache config. Now I'm trying to migrate onto Apache 2.4 and have difficulties with WSGI.

First of all: my server is on Windows 2008R2 (x64).

I setup Apache 2.4 x64 (httpd-2.4.10-win64-VC11.zip from Apache Lounge)
Then I downloaded mod_wsgi binary from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mod_wsgi - I took mod_wsgi‑3.5.ap24.win‑amd64‑py2.6.zip as Apache is x64 and my Python is 2.6.

In conf/httpd.conf I have

```
LoadModule mod_wsgi modules/mod_wsgi.so
```

I'm getting error when run httpd.exe:

httpd.exe: Syntax error on line 179 of C:/Prog/Apache24/conf/httpd.conf: Cannot load modules/mod_wsgi.so into server
: The specified module could not be found.

If I replace mod_wsgi.so with x86 version then I'll get other error about incorrect bitness, so the module seems to try be loaded.
I have all vsredist (2008/9,20010/10,2012/11) installed.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 4):

In my case the problem was wyth Python - it's x86 while everithing else is x64 (thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10447094/installing-mod-wsgi-module-for-apache)

Also the module import should be (thanks to [Can't locate API module structure `mod_wsgi'](https://serverfault.com/questions/435926/cant-locate-api-module-structure-mod-wsgi))

```
LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so
```

not

```
LoadModule mod_wsgi modules/mod_wsgi.so
```